# ¿Qué significa "use strict"?

Tags: javascript

A veces veo código que incluye `"use strict";`. Por ejemplo, muchas bibliotecas comienzan con esto:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
```

¿Qué significa "use strict" y para qué se usa?

---

En otros idiomas: [English](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/546661) • [Русский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/176684)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`"use strict";` (traducción: «usar estricto») es una directiva que activa la ejecución de código en el *modo estricto*. Sin esta directiva, el programa se ejecuta en el *modo irrestricto*.

El modo estricto se introdujo en ECMAScript 5, y navegadores viejos ([IE9 y menos](http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict)) no lo soportan. Es decir, lo ignoran y ejecutan todo en el modo irrestricto.

### ¿Para qué se usa `"use strict";`?

En el modo estricto,

- se pueden encontrar algunos errores más temprano,
- las partes más peligrosas o inútiles de JavaScript están prohibidas o lanzan un error de ejecución.

### ¿Cómo se usa `"use strict";`?

Para activar el modo estricto para todo el script, es necesario poner la directiva `"use strict";` o `'use strict';` al comienzo.

```
"use strict";
// el código aquí se ejecuta en el modo estricto
```

Para activar el modo estricto en una función, es necesario poner la directiva al comienzo de la función.

```
// el código aquí se ejecuta en el modo irrestricto
function f() {
  "use strict";
  // el código aquí se ejecuta en el modo estricto
}
// el código aquí se ejecuta en el modo irrestricto
```

### ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el modo estricto y el modo irrestricto?

En el modo estricto,

- **no se puede asignar un valor a una variable no definida** (especificación [§11.13.1](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1)). En el modo irrestricto se crea una variable global.

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    x = 5; // ReferenceError: x is not defined
  })(); 

  x = 5; // crea la variable global x
  ```

  Tampoco se puede asignar un valor a una propriedad de sólo lectura. En el modo estricto se lanza un error, y en el modo irrestricto está ignorada silenciosamente.

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    window.undefined = 5; // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only
  })();                   // property 'undefined' of [object Object]

  window.undefined = 5; // No hace nada
  ```
- **no se puede usar la instrucción `with`** (especificación [§12.10](http://es5.github.io/#x12.10)).

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    with(Object) {} // SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement
  })();
  ```
- **no se pueden definir propriedades duplicadas en un literal de objeto** (especificación [§11.1.5](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5)).

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var x = {
      a: 1,
      a: 2
    };  // SyntaxError: Duplicate data property in object literal 
  })(); // not allowed in strict mode

  var x = {
    a: 1,
    a: 2
  }; // x es igual a {a: 2}
  ```
- **no se pueden definir parametros duplicados en una función** (especificación [§13.1](http://es5.github.io/#x13.1), [§15.3.2](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.2)).

  ```
  function f(a, a) {
    "use strict";
  } // SyntaxError: Strict mode function may not have duplicate parameter names

  function f(a, a) {
    return a;
  }
  f(1,2); // regresa 2
  ```
- **cambios al objeto `arguments` no cambian los argumentos** (especificación [§10.6](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6)).

  ```
  function f(x) {
    "use strict";
    arguments[0] = 5;
    return x;
  }
  f(10); // regresa 10

  function f(x) {
    arguments[0] = 5;
    return x;
  }
  f(10); // regresa 5
  ```
- **`delete` lanza un error si el argumento no es una propriedad modificable de un objeto** (especificación [§11.4.1](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.1)).

  ```
  (function f(x) {
    "use strict";
    var y = 4;
    delete f; // SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
    delete x; // SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
    delete y; // SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
    delete window.undefined; // TypeError: Cannot delete property 
  })();                      // 'undefined' of [object Object]

  (function f(x) {
    var y = 4;
    delete f; // regresa false
    delete x; // regresa false
    delete y; // regresa false
    delete window.undefined; // regresa false
  })();
  ```
- **`eval` no puede instanciar variables y funciones fuera de su proprio contexto** (especificación [§10.4.2](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.2)).

  ```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    eval("var x = 5");
    return x; // ReferenceError: x is not defined
  })();

  (function () {
    eval("var x = 5");
    return x;
  })(); // regresa 5
  ```
- **`this` no se convierte en un objeto**, y **si `this` es `undefined` o `null` no se convierte en el objeto global** (especificación [§10.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3)).

  ```
  function f() {
    "use strict";
    return this;
  };
  f.call(4); // regresa 4
  f.call(null); // regresa null
  f.call(undefined); // regresa undefined

  function f() {
    return this;
  };
  f.call(4); // regresa [object Number]
  f.call(null); // regresa [object global]
  f.call(undefined); // regresa [object global]
  ```
- **no se pueden usar `eval` o `arguments` como nombres** (especificación [§11.4.4](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.4), [§11.4.5](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.5), [§11.13](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13), [§12.2.1](http://es5.github.io/#x12.2.1), [§12.10](http://es5.github.io/#x12.10), [§12.14.1](http://es5.github.io/#x12.14.1), [§13.1](http://es5.github.io/#x13.1)).

  ```
  function eval(arguments) {     // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    "use strict";
    eval = "5";                  // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    ++eval;                      // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    arguments++;                 // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    try {
      var arguments = 5;         // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    } catch(eval) {}             // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    return arguments.eval;
  }

  function eval(arguments) {
    eval = "5";
    ++eval;
    arguments++;
    try {
      var arguments = 5;
    } catch(eval) {}
    return arguments.eval;
  }
  eval(); // regresa 5
  ```
- **no se puede usar `argument.caller` y `arguments.callee`** (especificación [§13.2](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2)).

  ```
  (function f() {
    "use strict";
    arguments.caller; // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    arguments.callee; // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    f.arguments;      // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
  })();
  ```
- **hay más palabras reservadas para futuras versiones de ECMAScript** (especificación [§7.6.1.2](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.2)).

  ```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    var implements, let, private, public, yield, interface, package, protected, static;
  })(); // SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
  ```
- **no se pueden usar literales en base octal** (especificación [B.1.1](http://es5.github.io/#B.1.1), [B.1.2](http://es5.github.io/#B.1.2)).

  ```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    return 010 + // SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
      "\077";    // SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
  })();

  (function () {
    return 010 + "\077";
  })(); // regresa "8?"
  ```

---

Esta respuesta es una traducción de [mi respuesta a la misma pregunta en el sitio ruso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/176684).

Answer (score 4):

El uso de use-stric, añade al interprete del navegador como ejecutar el código javascript, esto te obliga a que necesitas declarar las variables antes de poder usarlas, ahora el uso de ellas puede variar, si quieres que afecte global mente, debes usarlo al inicio del código, o si quieres que afecta a una funcion podrías usarlo a continuación de la función

```
function showData(){
  var msj = "welcome";
  alert(msj)
}
```

en esta función el navegador ejecuta el código sin problema alguno. Pero si adicionamos use-strict.

```
function showData(){
  "use strict";
  msj = "welcome";
  alert(msj)
}
```

el navegador lanzara un error por no declarar antes la variable, para poder usarla, para ello deberás declarar la variable antes de usarla.

```
function showData(){
  "use strict";
  var msj = "welcome";
  alert(msj);

}
```

Esta y muchos criterios hacen parte del use-strict, por ejemplo definir una propiedad dos veces, parámetros duplicados etc, revisa la referencia y encontrás ejemplos